# chef spawn a background ruby process on windows

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, chef-infra

Is it possible using chef to spawn a new ruby process using its own ruby interpreter? Alternatively, is it possible to run ruby code asynchronously? My use case is an install file that I want to automate but it does not have a silent install option. I have an automate helper that uses `win32ole` to automate the install instead.

My current recipe uses a custom resource that looks like

```
action :install do
  # calling automate here happens too soon
  windows_package 'ESP' do
    # calling automate here won't happen until after the setup
    action :install
    source repo_from_version('sw', new_resource.version)
    installer_type :custom
    only_if { registry_data_exists?(csreg(node), :name => 'Version', :type => :string, :data => '6.0.0') }
  end
end

action_class do
  include MyModule::Helpers # defines automate
end
```

I thought I might place the automate code in its own file and use spawn to create a new ruby process before calling `windows_package` and have that process sleep for 3 seconds before trying to automate. But this server will not have ruby installed, except for the built-in chef interpreter.

Comment: Why not use a ruby_block resource?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. Or more specifically Chef has no handling for async actions overall.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a way around this. Using the template resource to create a powershell script that does the same thing and calling that with `system()` my problem with using another resource to manage this is that unless I'm mistaken all chef resources are blocking. I need the installer to be running when I execute the automate task.

Comment: Yeah, we have no stuff for concurrent process execution. You would have to build it yourself using threads and shell out helpers, or find another gem which can do it for you.